# Changing the color of certain pixels on a texture with SDL2

Tags: c, colors, sdl, pixel

I'm making a game with SDL2. I have a sprite sheet that I'm loading as a texture, and I'm drawing sprites off it onto the game window, like this:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, sprite_sheet_texture, &src_rect, &dst_rect);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

I want to specifically modify the color of every black pixels of every sprite in the texture during gameplay. Essentially I want to create a continuous glowing effect over time from black, to white, to black again.

[Here's an example of what a sprite looks like in the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg1PS.png)

[Here's what the effect I'm hoping to achieve looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfwqi.png)

The only way I've found I could use is to read the pixel data from the sprite sheet texture and manually update the color of every black pixel to a lighter shade. Then do it again and update that lighter pixel color to an even lighter one until the lightest has been reached, and repeat the process backwards.

The code (for just the first step of black pixels -> lighter shade at least) would look something like this:

```
Uint32* pixels;
int pitch;

SDL_LockTexture(sprite_sheet_texture, NULL, &pixels, &pitch);
SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, NULL, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, pixels, pitch);

// Get pixel count
SDL_PixelFormat* mapping_format = SDL_AllocFormat(SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888);
int pixel_count = (pitch / mapping_format->BytesPerPixel) * sprite_sheet_height;

// Swap every black pixel to a lighter shade
Uint32 from_pixel = SDL_MapRGBA(0, 0, 0, 255);
Uint32 to_pixel   = SDL_MapRGBA(24, 24, 24, 255);

for (int i = 0; i < pixel_count; i++) {
    if (pixels[i] == from_pixel} {
        pixels[i] = to_pixel;
    }
}

SDL_FreeFormat(mapping_format);
SDL_UnlockTexture(streaming_texture);
```

There's a couple of problems with this method:

1. It's slow. I haven't tested it yet, but the SDL documentation warns against using `SDL_RenderReadPixels` frequently as it's a "very slow operation". I would have to run the above code multiple times per second.
2. My sprite sheet would be unable to have certain pixel values within it. For example, if I'm updating pixels from "0, 0, 0" to "24, 24, 24" and then to "48, 48, 48", I'll have to make sure the sprite sheet does not have a single pixel with the values "24, 24, 24" or "48, 48, 48" since the above function would also update those pixels, while I just want to update the ones that were originally black.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Would it be simpler to have several textures available and cycle them?

Comment: You mean something like doing the above process for the sprite sheet several times, and store the results in 5 separate textures? That sounds like it could work, but I actually have more than one sprite sheet I might have to apply the effect to (up to 5). So that would mean 5 x 5 = 25 sprite sheets would have to be stored. I'm a bit worried about the space it would take up.

Comment: Have all the textures pre-prepared. Then you won't have to make any decisions about which pixels should be changed, you can do that offline.

Comment: That would fix both issues, but then I would still have to load multiple versions of the same texture in memory. They're quite large, I'm worried about it taking up too much space.

Comment: You asked *Is there a better way to accomplish this?* The images you link look like about 16x16 pixels. How is that a lot of memory? How much memory and execution time do you need to make changes to the image on-the-fly?

Comment: That's just a single sprite. The entire sprite sheet is 628x396, and I already need 5 different versions of it I'm generating at game start. Any of the 5 textures may need the glowing effect active at any given point. But actually I think it might be fine to generate the additional textures when I have to, keep them stored for as long as needed then later dispose of them.